# Is Linq to NHibernate in the 2.1 Alpha release?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

So the nHibernate 2.1 Alpha came out a few days ago, but the announcement on sourceforge doesn't mention the additional features. In particular, it doesn't mention whether LINQ is included. I know that I've read that LINQ would be part of 2.1, but that was 6 months ago. Anybody know if LINQ is in 2.1 or what new features are? There's no documenation about 2.1 alpha features on the official site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LinqToNHibernate is being [written](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/sstrong/archive/2009/03/09/628.aspx) by Steve Strong at IMeta. Steve is attempting an amazing task by changing the way NHibernate parses HQL from the string based system to an abstract syntax tree. To be fair he does have a head start as this is being done in  Hibernate using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) which he is porting to .Net. It still baffles my mind what he is undertaking. I must say well done to [IMeta](http://www.imeta.co.uk/) for giving Steve the time to work on this.

If you want to see how far he is going you can check the [uNhAddIns repository](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/).

There is also a workable LinqToNHibernate provider which you'll find in [NHContrib](http://nhcontrib.wiki.sourceforge.net/) I am using this on a few projects and it works well but isn't in active development now and does break down if you attempt complex Linq queries

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow Steve's blog to keep updated. And I agree, kudos to Steve for undertaking to re-write the nHibernate HQL parser.